# Creating method within Custom Class for Primary ID lookup based off other field

Tags: c#

This should be a pretty easy question.

**Context:**
I have a custom class that stores some information from a Database.
It stores a primary key (ID) and description/name.
I want to return the primary key by searching for a description/name.

This is my 1st C# program.

I am trying to use LINQ where to do the lookup.
It made sense to me that I should make the method for this be apart of the custom class that I created. **Do you agree?**

Where would you recommend I declare this method? Declaring within the class seems like the correct thing to do
**Why does the "This.Where" syntax not work? - I suppose its because its not a List< ClassTypeHere>**

```
class DM_DistEquip
    {
        public int ixPanel; //stores ID_Key relation to panel name
        public string sDescription; //stores name of panel
        public int iPanelType; //store ID_Key for type of panel

        public int distLookup(string pnl)
        {
            var dist = this.Where(x => x.sDescription == pnl).Select(y => y.ixPanel ).ToList(); //Lookup the primary key (ID) of the panel based of name of panel
            return dist; //return ID of the Panel Name
        }//end of method
    }
```

Comment: The LINQ where will always return only 1 entry. The information comes from a database where only each sDescription (name of the panel) can be used once. Is LINQ Where the best option for this? Returns as type List<int>, but really It will always only be a single value.

Comment: Think more about the difference between an instance and a type. `DM_DistEquip` is not a representation of ALL items in the table; rather, it is simply a place to store the fields from _one row_ of the table, nothing more. It might make sense that the type might know how to do this, but in the context of a specific instance, you'd either already know both values or neither, and the specific instance won't know anything at all about other rows in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you probably need an outer wrapper class where you can store your data as a collection. In there you can put your distLookup() if you want.

```
public class OuterClass()
{
   public List<DM_DistEquip> DistEquips {get;set;}

   public int distLookup(string pnl)
    {
        var dist = DistEquips.Where(x => x.sDescription == pnl).Select(y => y.ixPanel ).ToList(); //Lookup the primary key (ID) of the panel based of name of panel
        return dist; //return ID of the Panel Name
    }//end
    
}
```

That should help you get a better understanding.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I ended up doing this. I just felt as though the proper place to add method for manipulating the class should go in the class it's self. I suppose the only reason why this is not the case here is because the its a list<CustomClass> rather than just an operation on an object of the class itself. Thanks.